# The type or namespace name 'PersistentBag' does not exist in the namespace 'NHibernate.Collection'

Tags: c#, nhibernate, smartclient

I'm upgrading a Windows SmartClient solution from nHibernate 2.2 to 4.0, using NuGet in Visual Studio 2013.

On this line:

```
sb.Append ("=" + ((NHibernate.Collection.PersistentBag) state[i]).Count.ToString() + " items");
```

I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'PersistentBag' does not exist in the namespace 'NHibernate.Collection'

Suggested choices by Visual Studio (when typing the .) are:

- AbstractPersistentCollection
- Generic ( a namespace)
- IPersistentCollection (an interface)
- PersistentArrayHolder

The second and third are not classes. The first and fourth does not have a `Count()` method.

Which one have to be used in this case?

Comment: Nothing in the release notes? The visibility could be changed to internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `PersistentBag` in NHibernate 4, only `PersistentGenericBag<T>`.

It is an internal type of NH and not supposed to cast to.

I don't know where this code is actually found. If it is your own, you could access `Count` by `IList` or `ICollection`, which are both implemented by the bag.

If it is code from a framework you use, you probably have to use another NHibernate version.

Comment: Using `IColleciton` does compile at least: `sb.Append (propertyName[i].ToLower() + "=" +
               ((System.Collections.ICollection)state[i]).Count.ToString() + " items");`. I'll test this when I get the other problems solved.

Comment: If you are updating NHibernate, you should take a look at the release notes of all the versions since the one you used to use before. There are most often some more surprises at runtime ....

Answer (score 0):

I has code using this too.  It looks like you can replace the persistentBag cast with an IList cast.